# BST [homework] how does this method of iterative traversal work?

Tags: binary-search-tree, tree-traversal

I'm using an example from a free book Open Data Structures (in Java) by Pat Morin. I believe i understand the concept of what is going on for tree traversal (keep going left until you can't go any more left, then right and then back up.

I'm a little flummoxed on the code below however. How exactly does it know to change branches in a structure such as:

```
  r(oot)
  |
 -  -
|    |
a    b
   |  |
   c  d

void traverse2() {
     Node u = r, prev = nil, next;
     while (u != nil) {
       if (prev == u.parent) {
         if (u.left != nil) next = u.left;
         else if (u.right != nil) next = u.right;
         else next = u.parent;
       } else if (prev == u.left) {
         if (u.right != nil) next = u.right;
         else next = u.parent;
       } else {
         next = u.parent;
       }
       prev = u;
       u = next;
} }
```

from what I can see it automatically goes to parent even though the root has none?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root's parent is nil, so the algorithm terminates once it leaves the root by its parent (which it does after visiting the right subtree.)